# Why is GCP reporting lower CPU utilizations for the same node when monitored from K8S?

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, monitoring, cpu

I'm debugging CPU utilization in our kubernetes cluster.

When I open the page of a specific kubernetes node in a node pool, GCP reports an average of 14%.
But when I open the details of the same node from either Monitoring or Compute Engine -> VM Instances -> Observability I see twice the percentage.

Why such difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The discrepancy could be caused by several factors such as types of CPU utilization metrics such as User-level, System Level or Total CPU utilization. Also the data source could be one of the points to check as it can vary from time to time. Check as well the update frequency or time interval of the refresh since it can influence the report. Attached are documentations that can help you with your use case. [1][2]

[1] https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/metrics

[2] https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/metrics_gcp#gcp-compute

Comment: I see now that, under node observability -> CPU, the 2 graphs "CPU utilisation" and "CPU Usage vs. Reserved (vCPUs)" differ in the same way. The "CPU utilisation" pop up helper says "This may differ from the CPU utilisation as reported by the guest operating system", so at least this is known.
I'm still unsure which one I should use when evaluating VM resizing: I'll go with the latter since it's about my apps.